# How to get the square of a number for each cell in data frame in R

Tags: r

I have data frame in R with 3 columns A,B and C

```
A   B   C
2   3   4
5   2   7
```

I want to get square of each number like this

```
A   B   C
4   9  16
25  4  49
```

Can anyone please help me out. I can able to make in excel but want to do in R

Answer (score 1):

just do this. In R ^ will take care whether it is a number,vector,matrix or dataframe..

```
dataframe^2
```

If you want your result as a `data.frame` rather than a `matrix`, do

```
data.frame(dataframe^2)
```

Comment: Actually, this is potentially problematic as you are coercing from a `data.frame` to a `matrix` back to a `data.frame` and providing a chance to destroy information. `dat*dat` will maintain a `data.frame`, as will `data.frame(lapply(dat,"^",2))`